# tikzpicture pgf bar plot - Add Horizontal line that starts in axis and ends after 1st group of bars

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, bar-chart

I thought about doing an extra tick but the problem is that the line isn't applicable to all bars, only the "Weight" category. Is it possible to have a line starting on the axis and ending after Weight?

Here's the MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    simname     &   default &   rmat    &   cshell  \\
    Weight      &   29.1    &   69.2    &   60      \\
    F1L         &   56.0    &   159.9   &   70      \\
    F1U         &   84.9    &   241.1   &   60      \\
    F2L         &   56.0    &   159.9   &   80      \\
    F2U         &   84.9    &   241.1   &   90      \\
    F3L         &   41.5    &   113.5   &   40      \\
    F3U         &   63.2    &   171.5   &   60      \\
    F4U         &   77.4    &   220.1   &   50      \\
    F5U         &   77.4    &   220.1   &   80      \\
    F6U         &   57.6    &   156.5   &   120     \\
}\dispdata

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width  = \textwidth,
    height = 10cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=0.05pt,
    bar width=10pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel={Displacement~[\%~$L/200$]},
    symbolic x coords={Weight, F1L, F1U, F2L, F2U, F3L, F3U, F4U, F5U, F6U},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ymin=0,ymax=260,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
        at={(1,1.05)},
        anchor=south east,
        column sep=1ex
    },
    %extra y ticks = 100,
    %extra y tick labels={},
    %extra y tick style={grid=major,major grid style={very thick,draw=red}}
    ]
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=default] {\dispdata};
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=rmat]    {\dispdata};
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=cshell]  {\dispdata};
    \legend{Default, Removed Material, Complex Shell}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Comparison of Displacement Results from all Load Cases in the Different Simulation Configurations}
    \label{fig:ch4-dispcompare}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Currently have this:

[image]

And I'm looking for this:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use another `\addplot` to plot a line. Since the x-coordinates are symbolic, `normalized` coordinates can be used. The corresponding line looks like this:

```
\addplot[red,sharp plot,update limits=false,] coordinates { ([normalized]-1,100) ([normalized]0.5,100) };
```

`[normalized]0` corresponds to first x coordinate (`Weight`) and `[normalized]1` corresponds to second x coordinate (`F1L`). `[normalized]0.5` marks the midpoint between first and second. `[normalized]-1` was used to get the `xmin`.

output:

[image]

#### MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\pgfplotstableread[row sep=\\,col sep=&]{
    simname     &   default &   rmat    &   cshell  \\
    Weight      &   29.1    &   69.2    &   60      \\
    F1L         &   56.0    &   159.9   &   70      \\
    F1U         &   84.9    &   241.1   &   60      \\
    F2L         &   56.0    &   159.9   &   80      \\
    F2U         &   84.9    &   241.1   &   90      \\
    F3L         &   41.5    &   113.5   &   40      \\
    F3U         &   63.2    &   171.5   &   60      \\
    F4U         &   77.4    &   220.1   &   50      \\
    F5U         &   77.4    &   220.1   &   80      \\
    F6U         &   57.6    &   156.5   &   120     \\
}\dispdata

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
    width  = \textwidth,
    height = 10cm,
    major x tick style = transparent,
    ybar=0.05pt,
    bar width=10pt,
    ymajorgrids = true,
    ylabel={Displacement~[\%~$L/200$]},
    symbolic x coords={Weight, F1L, F1U, F2L, F2U, F3L, F3U, F4U, F5U, F6U},
    xtick = data,
    scaled y ticks = false,
    ymin=0,ymax=260,
    ytick style={draw=none},
    legend cell align=left,
    legend style={
        at={(1,1.05)},
        anchor=south east,
        column sep=1ex
    },]
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=default] {\dispdata};
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=rmat]    {\dispdata};
    \addplot table[x=simname,y=cshell]  {\dispdata};
    \addplot[red,sharp plot,update limits=false,] coordinates { ([normalized]-1,100) ([normalized]0.5,100) };
    \legend{Default, Removed Material, Complex Shell}
    \end{axis}
    \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{Comparison of Displacement Results from all Load Cases in the Different Simulation Configurations}
    \label{fig:ch4-dispcompare}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully! I tried using an addplot but instead added another bar to the graph unintentionally. Yours works perfectly, thank you very much!